# Are windows sids same from Windows 2000 through Windows 7?

Tags: security, windows-7, windows-2000

I've got some code that checks for a user to be in the admin group based on the SID.  Is this code going to work if the SID is hard-coded for Admin. for Windows 2000 SP4 through Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This TechNet article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330#appliesto) lists all server OSes from 2000-2008 R2, so it's safe to assume that they're all the same on the client counterparts as well.